# Sci-Fi movie with a stasis chamber for 1 but has to hold 2

Tags: space, story-identification

There was a movie in the late 1990's, early 2000's, that takes place aboard a ship. At the end of the movie, there is a man and woman who have to share a stasis pod, and there is gene transfers between them. And, the last seen is him having 1 green (blue) eye and 1 brown eye.

Can anyone please identify it for me?

Answer (score 16):

This is [Supernova](http://www.imdb.co.uk/title/tt0134983/), the stasis pods are required for their method of FTL travel (dimension jumps), which involves the ship "riding a beam of light".
The pods are dimension stabilization chambers, designed to only hold a single person, if more than one person shares a pod you can get "genetic swapping".

Comment: SteB - thanks. this has been driving my friend and i crazy for almost a week

Comment: @user13902 - welcome to the site, it is an average film, the dimension jumps are the bits that really stand out. Please accept this answer if it's correct.